# Need help determining data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary

Sorry that I couldn't come up with a better title for the question.

I'm trying to load all the rows and columns from any table and store it in a data structure for comparison.  Since this can be any table, I'm thinking:

```
Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,string>>
// The int will hold the row number
// The second dictionary will hold column,value
```

Is it a good idea to use this for this scenario?  I will mainly be inserting and searching.  If there are any other suggestions, please let me know.  I'm fairly new to data structures.

Comment: What is the purpose of int? A hashcode for the row? Or are all your rows PK'd with an int?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry about that.  Will keep in mind. =)

Comment: @StuartLC Yes the PK.  To begin with I'm keeping it int (for my tests), but might change it to string to support GUIDs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource, 
    ISupportInitializeNotification, ISupportInitialize, ISerializable, IXmlSerializable
```

> Represents one table of in-memory data.

It will allow you to have a table with different type for each column. Your `Dictionary` solution only allows all columns to have the same type.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? =)  That is actually a good idea.  I saw that weakness of my dictionary, along with others.  I will give the DataTable a go and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks that works much better!